# How to debug a plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with a few projects, one of which compiles to a DLL and defines an interface to create a plugin. All these projects together make up a standard product.

Now, a have created another solution with a single project, that references that DLL and implements a plugin.

When debugging, I am running the standard product and load the plugin during runtime. Of course, I can debug all the code of the standard product, but how can I debug the plugin code?

Comment: Make sure the PDB is available or reference the project.

Comment: @leppie the PDB is available, in the same dir as the driver DLL. But, how can I set a breakpoint for example?

Comment: Opening the source code file from the original location and setting a breakpoint should work. The breakpoint will only turn 'red' once the plugin DLL is loaded. Another option is to just call `Debugger.Break()` in the init function of your plugin and things should just work.

Comment: @leppie I did set a breakpoint in the code, but that didn't work. As I said, the plugin is in a different solution, which I currently run in a different instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Try my second suggestion, that normally works.

Comment: @leppie thats right, that works. I don't really like to alter code for debugging, but it is at least something.

Comment: Good! You can now try make sure everything is the same (filepaths of source files, etc) and try option 1 again.

Comment: You are right. It all works, I just had to open the source file in the right solution. I never reckoned it was this simple ;-)).

Comment: I have been caught out with that too many times :) Post your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was way easier than anticipated. I just opened the `.cs` file I wanted to debug in the solution with the standard product and I could put a breakpoint there.

All in all, it Just Worked™ and I never tried this, because I thought it wouldn't.